# xcode 13 build issues

Tags: xcode, macos-big-sur, xcode13, ios15

I currently updated my spare phone to ios 15 developer beta to begin fixes for ios 15 on my app and was forced to upgrade my mac os to big sur as well as download xcode 13 beta and ever since then have run into so many headaches. I can never successfully build my app in xcode and always run into issues with SDKs like facebook login in and others even after running my app commenting them out of my podfile or even updating the files there seems to be something always wrong. I try building my app in the regular xcode 12.5 and still have the same build issues which I never had before upgrading to big sur. This is very frustrating as I have wasted many hours trying to fix this with no solution. Is anyone else having issues or have had the same issues that I am facing?

Comment: Xcode 13 is a beta. If you mean your issues are Xcode's fault, report a bug. But I guess the issues are related to incompatible dependencies.